# oracle 6i form date compare trigger

Tags: oracle

so i m trying to figure out how to setup a trigger in oracle 6i forms that force user to not enter date if its like 02.15.2018  means if i setup that this form accepts date entry only between 2016 to 2017 and if user try to enter 2018 date or month then error should pop up
 i have already setup the calender and this is the code i m using for calender lov to work

```
DECLARE
    XP NUMBER;
    YP NUMBER;
BEGIN
    XP:=GET_ITEM_PROPERTY('DATE_',X_POS);
    YP:=GET_ITEM_PROPERTY('DATE_',Y_POS);
    date_lov.get_date(sysdate,'DATE_',xp,yp,'From Date','OK','Cancel',TRUE,FALSE,FALSE);
end;
```

check this image
[form expiry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wzRP.jpg)

as u can see i m trying to achieve is like software expiry system so that user can use 1year than he get a message that your software is going to expire so purchase a license or 30day trial ver etc, so far what research i did i found this 
[oracle software expiry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fByPNmKtnE8)

but my form has no login user system so i cannot apply this as u can see here my main form
[main form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcAXd.jpg)

thats why i m looking to achieve this on date entry level so that if user try to change system date he still wont able to enter date as i want our trigger wont use sysdate coz by using sysdate he can manuplate, let me know if u need more info, and thanks for early rply it was helpful

Comment: What x and y positions has to do with comparing dates and restricting your LOV? And why can't you restrict dates in your LOV query?

Comment: this code is use to call that calender lov, i m new to oracle so dont know that much all i want is in date field user cant put 2019 or above date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not want to re-write your code every year. Like next year you will need data that less than year 2020, etc... First, look at EXTRACT in Oracle documentation (SQL Reference) or books. There are gazillion examples online and here.

The first step is to set up your "trigger year" dynamically somewhere in your code. You want all rows in your code that are less or equal to the current year only as I understood. You can do this in forms or back end - depends on your requirements and rules:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (trunc(SYSDATE))) 
  INTO trigger_year
  FROM dual
/
```

The EXTRACT will return number. So, your 'trigger_year' must be number. The above code will give you the year portion of the current year. So, the next year you will sleep well. ))

Next, in your forms trigger you can do smth lk this - all depends on your requirements:

1. to restrict your LOV data making changes to the LOV query with same EXTRACT example.
2. or write validation trigger on your calendar item with similar code - apply EXTRACT to the :block.clndr_date, must be the same datatype on both sides to compare:

   IF :block.clndr_date <= trigger_date THEN 
    raise error and show message to the user; 
   END IF;
3. or do all of above.

General example - changing the year portion of dt1 to 2019 will return no rows:

```
WITH test_data AS
(
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM (to_date('19-APR-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))) dt1
 , EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM (trunc(SYSDATE))) trigger_date
  FROM dual
)
SELECT dt1 FROM test_data
WHERE dt1 <= trigger_date
/
```

Comment: To check for what? I think I answered the question.

Comment: if u can take a look, i have included screenshots, maybe u can give better solution

Comment: First, I do not see any screen shots. Second, your description says -  restrict your data to only current year and not next year. And this is exactly what I did. Did i miss anything? If you do not like it then no problem, I'm not here for scores. You should probably think how to describe problems more clearly. I do not have any better solution to the question and how you described your problem. it seems very easy to me. I will not waste any more time on this unless you want to CLEARLY describe what you want.

Comment: I'm very glad, bro ))

Comment: i just try to did is describe my situation more , i have edited my main post, (see below my posted code) if u can kindly take a look it will be very helpful for me

Comment: You can replace the sysdate with any date in my example. Use your system date instead. This is all I can suggest. Add 365 days to your system date to validate and force the user to buy a licence or smth... You can do this in both, block level and in your LOV query. Not sure what else to suggest. I used the sysdate in my example only to extract current year and compare the current year to the year entered by the user. If user enters 2019 the validation will fail and you can show message to the user. That's all. Then, if user buys trial or extends you need to add login to extend...